# How to generate a hashable key out of a method call expression tree in C#?

Tags: c#, caching, expression-trees

I need a generic cache mechanism for method calls.

Say I have a uncached call, like this:

```
var output = impl.GetById(guid);
```

I came up with a cache utility that allows me to write:

```
var output = _cache.Cache((i) => i.GetById(guid));
```

Where `_cache = new Cache(impl)`. The idea is that `cache.Cache` will return a cached value if `GetById(guid)` does not change.

To make it work properly, I need to produce a reliable key out of `i.GetById(guid)`. How do I do that?

Here is my naive implementation:

```
    public class Cache<I>
    {
        private I _impl;
        private MemoryCache _cache;

        public Cache(I impl, MemoryCache cache = null)
        {
            _impl = impl;
            _cache = cache ?? MemoryCache.Default;
        }

        public R Cached<R>(Expression<Func<I, R>> expr)
        {
            var keyBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            var methodExpr = expr.Body as MethodCallExpression;
            keyBuilder.Append(methodExpr.Method.Name);
            var args = new object[methodExpr.Arguments.Count];
            for (int i = 0; i < args.Length; ++i)
            {
                var lambdaExp = Expression.Lambda(methodExpr.Arguments[i]);
                args[i] = lambdaExp.Compile().DynamicInvoke();
                keyBuilder.AppendFormat(" {0}:{1}",
                    (args[i] ?? "").GetType().Name,
                    RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(args[i]));
            }

            var key = keyBuilder.ToString();
            var lazy = new Lazy<object>(() =>
            {
                try { return methodExpr.Method.Invoke(_impl, args); }
                catch (TargetInvocationException e) { return e.InnerException; }
                catch (Exception e) { return e; }
            });
            var offset = DateTimeOffset.UtcNow.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
            var oldLazy = (Lazy<object>)_cache.AddOrGetExisting(key, lazy, offset);
            object value = (oldLazy != null) ? oldLazy.Value : lazy.Value;

            var exception = value as Exception;
            if (exception != null) throw exception;

            return (R)value;
        }
    }
```

Update:

Just to make things more clear. My intention is to use this caching mechanism to cache DB calls. In my case, arguments are mostly primitive types (+string) and there is always a single output (the returned object).

Here is an example of interface:

```
public interface ITransactionDb {
   Trasaction GetById(Guid id);
   IList<Transaction> ListTransactions(Datetime start, Datetime end, string origin = null);
}
```

However, I'd like this design to be robust enough to cache, say, RPC calls in which case input parameter is an non-primitive.

Al alternative and much simpler design could be:

```
    public class Cache {
        public R Cached<R>(Func<R> method)
        {
            var key = GenerateKey(method.Method);
            return GetOrAdd(key, method);
        }

        public R Cached<T1, R>(Func<T1, R> method, T1 t1)
        {
            var key = GenerateKey(method.Method, t1);
            return GetOrAdd(key, () => method(t1));
        }

        public R Cached<T1, T2, R>(Func<T1, T2, R> method, T1 t1, T2 t2)
        {
            var key = GenerateKey(method.Method, t1, t2);
            return GetOrAdd(key, () => method(t1, t2));
        }
   }
```

Cached call would look like:

```
var transaction = cache.Cache(impl.GetById, guid);
```

Comment: Can you post your `I` class?

Comment: Side note: in general you can't use HashCode for cache key as it does not  guarantee uniqueness... You need to rely on some sort of convention/interface/switch to get reliable cache key components from each argument by its type.

Comment: I'm having a hard time understanding what you're getting at here. Are you trying to memoize the call?

Comment: You said, "cache.Cache will return a cached value if GetById(guid) does not change." But how will you know it hasn't changed? If you have to run it to detect a change, you're not caching. It sounds to me like you're not clear on what you want to happen. Caching is generally done either by lifetime (cache for 5 minutes or 5 hours) or when a less-expensive query can be done that determines if the value has changed. If so, then you run the expensive query to get the real value (as in the case of a HEAD request to a web server). When will you cache, and when will you recalculate?

Comment: I meant the tuple ("GetBy", contentof(guide)) does not change. In other words, if operation and inputs don't change in a given amount of time, return cached output value.

Answer (score 0):

Can your input parameters be both value types and reference types? Do you have equality comparison strategy defined for reference types? Can you produce a unique string value (from equality point of view) from any reference type instance? If yes, you can build a key as a string using any acceptable form of values separation.

If you can't choose separation character such as '_' or '|' then you can get more creative and define a format, such as

"3_4_abcd_6_12_456_10_DHXSS94HGF"

which deciphers:
3 - number of parameters
4 - length of the first parameter
abcd - value of the first parameter
6 - length of the second parameter
12_456 - value of the second parameter
10 - length of the third parameter
DHXSS94HGF - value of the third parameter

as variation of that is representing parameters and values as query string
a=abcd&b=12_456&c=DHXSS94HGF

but again it goes to your restriction on character set.

you can get somewhat creative on other multiple possible way to generate a string representing set of parameters, but the hardest part here is to be able to define convertion from object to a string that generates a string value that is the same for two different instances with logically the same value.

[update] using separators is somewhat important to avoid unwanted collisions. so imagine you have

```
string Func(int a, int b) { ... }
// then
Func(12,3);
Func(1,23);
```

if you don't use value separators both would generate key "123" while you probably want two different keys "12_3" and "1_23"

Comment: This is targeting calls to DB, thus arguments are mostly primitives (+ string). There is a single output (return).

Comment: then just append them together. if you think it will generate too long of a key, get a cryptographic hash over it, such as sha256 or sha512 that would give a good enough uniqueness. However it looks like MemoryCache class doesn't enforce any length limit on they key, so it should not be needed. Choose a separator character that is unlikely to be present in value and concatenate them.

Answer (score 0):

Move the problem to argument serialization. If ur method is stable, and you know nothing about the parameters, require serializability.
You obviously wont be able to use it with e.g Streams, but it might be ok for your use case...